# How can i combine more then one database's data in one database with same schema

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a 5 database with same schema, i want to copy all data in one database with same schema
or how can i copy data from *.mdf files in database.
i am using sql server 2005

Comment: Schema being the same is not enough. How will you handle PK violations? I mean if there are tables with identity property for PK, then is is almost certain that you will have data with the same PK value in each DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy Database with T-SQL:

[sqlauthority](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/07/29/sql-server-2008-copy-database-with-data-generate-t-sql-for-inserting-data-from-one-table-to-another-table/)

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/07/29/sql-server-2008-copy-database-with-data-generate-t-sql-for-inserting-data-from-one-table-to-another-table/

Copy Database with Wizard:

[kodyaz](http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-tools/sql-server-copy-database-wizard.aspx)

http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-tools/sql-server-copy-database-wizard.aspx

Comment: Sorry unable to access these links

Comment: i access only last link another one is block by our administration

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest taking a look at Red Gate SQL Data Compare. That will enable you to merge the data between the two databases and directly control which one wins in any given situation.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above you need to deal with the Primary Keys as well...

One way to deal with this to add a "Database ID" to all the tables in the single central version. The central PKs become the PK from the source table, plus the "Database ID".  This way you have unique PKs in the central version AND you can tell which database the row came from. This is what [sql-hub](http://sql-hub.com) does - there is a free licence which will let you do this as a one-off task - or you could do the inserts for each database and table in SQL.